# Mask input the phone number JavaScript

Tags: javascript, expression, mask

I need to develop a pattern of input numbers, must start with a digit 2 and still have 6 digits or begin with "(012)2" and 6 digits, or else as "290-53-21" I made on the number of digits and the starting number 2, and on the dash(-), but I can not do at "(012)" how to write it?
My code:

```
function checkNumber(str){
    if(!str.length)
         alert("error");
     var tmp = new RegExp("(2?|\([032]{3}\)?)[0-9-]{6,9}");
     str = str.replace(tmp, "");
     if(str != "")
         alert("error");
}
```

Comment: mask number can be:1)2345678 or (012)2345678 or 234-65-34

Comment: Is this statement correct? --- Input must be a 7-digit number starting with a `2`, may have an optional prefix of `(012)` and optional dashes (exactly 0 dashes or exactly 2 dashes) after the 3rd and 5th digits `2nn-nn-nn`

Comment: use <input type=tel> for best UX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one seems to do the trick:

```
^(((\(012\))\d|2)\d{6}|2\d{2}(-\d{2}){2})$
```

It's like this:

- ^ and $ are start and end...
- The regular expression is like this `^( x | y )$`
- where x is `((\(012\))\d|2)\d{6}`, this will match (012)d or a 2 with
  `((\(012\))\d|2)` and 6 digits with `\d{6}`
- and where y is `2\d{2}(-\d{2}){2}`, for a `2` followed by 2 digits `\d{2}`, and followed by two times -dd `(-\d{2}){2}`

Comment: are you check this code with my function, I checked and it isn't work(

Comment: @badCoder  Try this in your console `/^((\(012\))?2\d{6}|2\d{2}(-\d{2}){2})$/.test('2222222')`

Comment: it's good)), but if i try to input (012)245-65-78, result - false

Comment: but it's not necessarily, Thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

```
var t = /^(?:\(012\))?2(?:\d{6}|\d{2}(?:-\d{2}){2})$/
t.test(2123456); // true
t.test('212-31-23'); // true
t.test('(012)212-31-23'); // true
t.test('(012)2123123'); // true
t.test('(012)212-34-56'); // true

t.test('((012)2123456245-11-11'); // false
```

Here's how it works:

**/^** - indicates the beggining

**(?:(012))?** - accepts (012) or nothing

**2** - the initial 2

**(?:A|B)** - accepts either 6 digits like so: 'aaaaaa' or 'aa-aa-aa'

where A = **\d{6}**

and B = **\d{2}(?:-\d{2}){2}**

Hopefully that helps.